# Previous row value to be fetched

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Here I want to get the previous row balance value in to my field.

The last id of customer_id '16' of balance is 200, but I want to get the previous ids value in to the field and this is my table

```
    id  order_id    customer_id  amount     actual_amount   paid_amount     balance     type
    25  11            16                        100.00        50.00         50.00       Cash
    26  12            16                        200.00        100.00        100.00      Cash
    27  13            16                        150.00        100.00        50.00       Cash
    28  14            16                        300.00        250.00        50.00       Cash
    29  14            16                        170.00        100.00        70.00       Cash
    30  15            16         100            170.00        70.00         100.00      Cash
    31  16            16         400            500.00        300.00        200.00      Cash
```

this is my model

```
public function order_balance($order_code)
{
    $this->db->join('services','payment.customer_id=services.customer_id','left');
    $this->db->select('payment.*,payment.balance,payment.actual_amount,payment.customer_id');
    $this->db->order_by('payment.id','desc');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('payment',array('code' => $order_code));
    return $query->previous_row();
}
```

This is my control:

```
 public function final_payment($order_code)
{
    $data['active_mn']='';
    $data['result'] = $this->Account_model->order_balance($order_code); 
    $this->load->view('final_payment',$data);
}
```

My services table looks like this:

```
    id  code      customer_id   particulars     
    11  ORD00011    16              phone   
    12  ORD00012    16              gdf     
    13  ORD00013    16              ghgfh   
    14  ORD00014    16               tv     
    15  ORD00015    16              ghfg    
    16  ORD00016    16               tv     
    17  ORD00017    16              gdfg    
    18  ORD00018    16              desk    
    19  ORD00019    16              gdf
```

My result should be like this:

```
 id      order_id    customer_id     amount    actual_amount   paid_amount  balance     type
 31        16            16           400         500.00         300.00     100.00      Cash
```

Comment: the last id of customer_id '16' balance value should be 100

Comment: The services table is not relevant to this problem, right?

Comment: yes the service table is not relevant to this but code included in services table is required to get the desired page

Comment: But it's a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN, so I don't quite see why it matters. ?!?!

Comment: k it doesn't matter is there any trick in codeigniter to find the previous row value

Answer (score 1):

One option here would be to do a self join with the `payment` table, joining on the `customer_id` and `order_id` columns.  You can add another join function call and then use the result in your select.  The following solution uses a raw query since Codeigniter does not seem to tolerate arithmetic in the join condition:

```
public function order_balance($order_code)
{
    $this->db->query("SELECT p1.*, p2.balance AS previous_balance FROM payment p1 INNER JOIN payment p2 ON p1.order_id = p2.order_id + 1 AND p1.customer_id = p2.customer_id LEFT JOIN services s ON p1.customer_id = s.customer_id ORDER BY p1.id DESC");
    $query = $this->db->get_where('p1', array('code' => $order_code));
    return $query->previous_row();
}
```

The query has the form:

```
SELECT p1.*, p2.balance AS previous_balance
FROM payment p1 INNER JOIN payment p2
    ON p1.order_id = p2.order_id + 1 AND
       p1.customer_id = p2.customer_id
LEFT JOIN services s
    ON p1.customer_id = s.customer_id
ORDER BY p1.id DESC
```

Comment: getting an error like this `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 and `payment`.`customer_id` = `p1`.`customer_id` WHERE `code` = 'ORD00019' ORD' at line 4`

Comment: You may have to use a raw query here.

Comment: getting this error  `Table 'billpay_service.p1' doesn't exist`

Comment: @MOHAMMED I won't make any further updates until you update your question with the _exact_ table and column names in your actual problem.  If you do this, then first we will get the raw query in MySQL, then we will figure out the Codeigniter stuff.

Comment: see am having tables such as payment and services

Comment: Update your question showing us all relevant tables and some sample data.  You will at least get a functioning MySQL query, and you can work with that in your Codeigniter code.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways of writng this. Here's one way. I don't know codeigniter, so you'll have to reverse engineer it...

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.order_id
     , a.customer_id
     , a.amount
     , a.actual_amount
     , a.paid_amount
     , b.balance 
     , a.type
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MAX(y.id) prev 
         FROM payment x 
         JOIN payment y 
           ON y.id < x.id 
          AND y.customer_id = x.customer_id 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
     ) a 
  JOIN payment b 
    ON b.id = a.prev 
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```