# getting unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

am getting an error like

```
Unknown column 'code' in 'where clause'
SELECT * FROM `payment` WHERE `code` = 'ORD00023'
```

even though i had used joined method for joining of payment table and services table.Here iam finding the solution of previous row value but its not getting.

this is my model

```
public function order_balance($order_code)
{
$this->db->query("
SELECT p1.*
      , p2.balance AS previous_balance 
  FROM payment p1 
  JOIN payment p2 
    ON p1.order_id = p2.order_id + 1 
   AND p1.customer_id = p2.customer_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN services s 
    ON p1.customer_id = s.customer_id 
 ORDER BY p1.id DESC
");
$query = $this->db->get_where('payment p1', array('code' => $order_code));
return $query;
}
```

this is my table payment

```
id  order_id    customer_id  amount     actual_amount   paid_amount     balance     type
25  11            16                        100.00        50.00         50.00       Cash
26  12            16                        200.00        100.00        100.00      Cash
27  13            16                        150.00        100.00        50.00       Cash
28  14            16                        300.00        250.00        50.00       Cash
29  14            16                        170.00        100.00        70.00       Cash
30  15            16         100            170.00        70.00         100.00      Cash
31  16            16         400            500.00        300.00        200.00      Cash
```

this is table services

```
id  code      customer_id   particulars     
11  ORD00011    16              phone   
12  ORD00012    16              gdf     
13  ORD00013    16              ghgfh   
14  ORD00014    16               tv     
15  ORD00015    16              ghfg    
16  ORD00016    16               tv     
17  ORD00017    16              gdfg    
18  ORD00018    16              desk    
19  ORD00019    16              gdf
```

Here i have joined the payment table and services table but still not getting

see my table

```
id  order_id    customer_id     amount  actual_amount   paid_amount     balance     type
50  31             16           650         750.00        250.00        500.00      Cash
51  1              16           100         600.00        300.00        300.00      Cash
52  2              16           100         400.00        200.00        200.00      Cash
53  3              16           800         1000.00       600.00        400.00      Cash
54  4              15           400         400.00        300.00        100.00      Cash
55  5              15           500         600.00        575.00        25.00       Cash
56  6              16           350         750.00        600.00        150.00      Cash
```

in this table the customer_id of `16` having the previous row value of balance 25 and am getting like this but i want the last customer_id `16` balance value as the previous customer_id `16` value.
for example my result should look like this

```
id     order_id    customer_id   amount   actual_amount   paid_amount   balance     type
56       6         16          350          750.00        600.00        400.00      Cash
```

Comment: in table payment p1 ..use column_names that you want instead of astrick and use column name code with alias of table_name service

Comment: i had used column name code with alias of table_name service but still not getting

Comment: You didn't include `code` in the SELECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want this?

```
$this->db->query("SELECT p1.*, p2.balance AS previous_balance FROM payment p1 INNER JOIN payment p2 ON p1.order_id = p2.order_id + 1 AND p1.customer_id = p2.customer_id LEFT JOIN services s ON p1.customer_id = s.customer_id AND s.code = ? ORDER BY p1.id DESC", array($order_code));
```

Comment: your answer looks good to me but the problem is if there is many customer_id how can i get the last row of same customer_id

Comment: For your sample data, could you give us your expected result? And you are trying to ask a new question, I think you should ask it on SO.

Comment: the question which i asked is alredy here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37784644/previous-row-value-to-be-fetched/37789126#37789126

Comment: @MOHAMMED About that question, you did not get an answer for it?

Comment: your answer makes me very happy but when i changed it in to codeigniter its not working but in your demo  its working nicely

Comment: no error but not getting see my answer which i had posted

Comment: now i got it thanks a lot you made my day such a great one..thanks alot

Comment: i had made some changes in your code and find it out

Comment: That's great. @MOHAMMED

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are writing two different query

To see add `$this->db->last_query()` after both. You will see two queries are executing.

```
//1st query

$this->db->query("SELECT p1.*, p2.balance AS previous_balance FROM payment p1
INNER JOIN payment p2 ON p1.order_id = p2.order_id + 1 AND p1.customer_id 
= p2.customer_id LEFT JOIN services s ON p1.customer_id = s.customer_id 
ORDER BY p1.id DESC");
echo  $this->db->last_query();

//2nd query
$query = $this->db->get_where('payment p1', array('code' => $order_code));
echo  $this->db->last_query();
```

both are independent from each other.

**Try this**

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT p1.*, p2.balance AS previous_balance FROM payment p1
INNER JOIN payment p2 ON p1.order_id = p2.order_id + 1 AND p1.customer_id 
= p2.customer_id LEFT JOIN services s ON p1.customer_id = s.customer_id 
where code='".$order_code."'  ORDER BY p1.id DESC");
```

**OR**

```
$this->db->select('p1.*, p2.balance AS previous_balance');
$this->db->from('payment p1');
$this->db->join('payment p2','p1.order_id = p2.order_id + 1 AND p1.customer_id 
= p2.customer_id','');
$this->db->join('services s','p1.customer_id = s.customer_id','left');
$this->db->where('s.code',$order_code);
$this->db->order_by('p1.id', 'DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is showing error because you are missing alias of table name, in which column code is available. replace code

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('payment p1', array('code' => $order_code));
```

with

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('payment p1', array('services.code' => $order_code));
```

or

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('payment p1', array('s.code' => $order_code));
```

Answer (score 0):

This changes i had made in my model and got the result

```
public function order_balance($order_code)
{

  $query=$this->db->query("SELECT payment.*, t3.balance AS pre_balance FROM payment 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) AS id, customer_id FROM payment GROUP BY customer_id) t ON payment.id = t.id AND payment.customer_id = t.customer_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT t1.* FROM payment t1
  WHERE (
    SELECT count(*) FROM payment t2 WHERE t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id AND t1.id <= t2.id
) <= 2
AND t1.id not IN (SELECT max(id) FROM payment GROUP BY customer_id)) t3 ON payment.customer_id = t3.customer_id LEFT JOIN services s ON payment.customer_id = s.customer_id AND s.code = ? ", array($order_code)); 
 return $query;
}
```